# rails 5 mysql adapter issue

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

Am trying to create a model in rails 5 and have installed  mysql-community-server. Also I have installed both mysql and mysql2 gem's. But when i run `rails generate model Book` getting below error,

```
[root@server-linux library]# rails generate model Book
/root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require': Could not load 'active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter'. Make sure that the adapter in config/database.yml is valid. If you use an adapter other than 'mysql2', 'postgresql' or 'sqlite3' add the necessary adapter gem to the Gemfile. (LoadError)
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:174:in `spec'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:53:in `establish_connection'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:125:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `instance_eval'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `execute_hook'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:45:in `block in run_load_hooks'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `each'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `run_load_hooks'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/base.rb:324:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/base.rb:24:in `<top (required)>'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:338:in `active_record_configured?'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:259:in `disconnect_database'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:97:in `preload'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:143:in `serve'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:131:in `block in run'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `loop'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `run'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from -e:1:in `<main>'
[root@server-linux library]#
```

database.yaml:

```
[root@server-linux library]# cat config/database.yml
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: library_development
  username: root
  password: [password]
  host: localhost

test:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: library_test
  username: root
  password: [password]
  host: localhost

production:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: library_production
  username: root
  password: [password]
  host: localhost

[root@server-linux library]#
```

Version details:

```
[root@server-linux library]# rails -v
Rails 5.0.0
[root@karthick-linux library]# gem list | grep mysql
activerecord-mysql-adapter (0.0.1)
mysql (2.9.1)
mysql2 (0.4.4)
[root@server-linux library]#
```

Even I created application with the command `rails new library -d mysql`

Any idea why its failing with mysql adapter connection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try installing `bundler`. I am guessing that `mysql2` gem is installed for different version of ruby and not your current version of ruby. Try installing `bundler` first.

```
gem install bundler
bundle install   
rails db:migrate
rails g model book
```

Also you won't need `mysql` gem, you can just delete it and use `mysql2` as adapter in your `database.yml` file.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Removal of `mysql` gem worked.

Answer (score 0):

**Check your Gem file**

in your gem file find `gem 'mysql2'`

if not found please add `gem 'mysql2'` then run `bundle install` and restart server.

Comment: respective db type gem file entry exists on Gemfile and I double confirmed the same. Also I tried with postgresql, sqlite3 as well where I ended up with the same issue.